# groupingBy in Streams with CollectingAndThen method -> how to get rid of Optional then use Max on the map :)

Tags: java, sorting, stream, java-stream, groupingby

Seems like i do not quite understand the concepts of groupingBy & collectors & sorting.

Task: to sum the number of order's quantity grouped by Category using Streams. Then get category with Max quantity and print it out on the picture as single map row with top value

3 classes (2 Records: Product & Order + Main). In Main there is an List.of new orders

Class Product:

```
public record Product(String name, BigDecimal price, String category)
```

Class Order:

```
public record Order(Product product, int quantity, BigDecimal discount)

public BigDecimal priceWithDiscount(){
    return product.price().multiply(BigDecimal.ONE.subtract(discount));
}
```

Class Main

```
       List<Order> orders = List.of(
            new Order(new Product("chleb", new BigDecimal(5), "A"),10, new BigDecimal("0.1")),
            new Order(new Product("maslo", new BigDecimal(6), "A"),5, new BigDecimal("0.2")),
            new Order(new Product("szynka", new BigDecimal(25), "B"),10, new BigDecimal("0")),
            new Order(new Product("kielbasa", new BigDecimal(16),"C"),5, new BigDecimal("0")),
            new Order(new Product("woda", new BigDecimal(3),"B"),15, new BigDecimal("0.1")),
            new Order(new Product("ocet", new BigDecimal(3),"A"),8, new BigDecimal("0.3")),
            new Order(new Product("margaryna", new BigDecimal(4),"B"),12, new BigDecimal("0.5")),
            new Order(new Product("maslo", new BigDecimal(8),"C"),5, new BigDecimal("0.2"))
            )
```

Below my implementation of grouping:

```
        Map<String, Optional<Integer>> summedQuantitiesPerCategory = orders //no 1.
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.product().category(),
                    Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                            Collectors.mapping(p -> p.quantity(), Collectors.toList()),
                            quantity -> quantity.stream().reduce((x, y) -> x + y) 
                    )));


        summedQuantitiesPerCategory
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(p -> p.getValue())) // no2.
            .limit(1);
```

Questions:

1. How to get rid of this Optional and see only Integer as a value in the map. Then it would be easy to sort i guess
2. How to sort map via Value using method Sorted or something more simple like e.g. max?

Comment: You can use `Collectors.toMap` also `orders.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.product().category(), p -> p.quantity(), (a,b) -> a + b));`

Comment: “or something more simple like e.g. max” How about consulting [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#:~:text=max%28), at least once in a lifetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the one argument version of `reduce` which accepts a `BinaryOperator`. You can pass an identity value along with the `BinaryOperator`.

```
quantity -> quantity.stream().reduce(0, (x, y) -> x + y)
```

or

```
quantity -> quantity.stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum)
```

Since you just want to sum the quantity, you can use `Collectors.summingInt`

```
...
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.product().category(),
                Collectors.summingInt(p -> p.quantity())));
```

Comment: All solutions work, thank you very much, now not only i do have code, my whole concept is more clear to me. Thanks one more time!!